# Swift: Unable to call removeFromSuperview() on custom view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm trying to add a progress indicator to my app. First I create an **overlayView** and add it to self.navigationController!.view and then add the **SwiftProgressView** to the **overlayView**.

This works perfectly but the problem is when I try to remove the ** SwiftProgressView**... When I call `removeFromSuperview()` on **SwiftProgressView** The app crashes with the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is how I'm creating my views (AIView is a custom view i've created that has the activity indicator in it):

```
private var AIView: ActivityIndicatorView?
private var overlayView: UIView?
```

This is how I'm trying to remove them:

```
    if let xy = AIView {
        xy.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    overlayView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

I don't know why I cant call `.removeFromSuperview()` directly on ActivityIndicatorView but by unwrapping the optional ActivityIndicatorView? i can call the `.removeFromSuperview()` but i get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If anyone can figure out what the problem is here that would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

--- --- EDIT

After failing to figure out what the problem was I've recreated the same scenario with a test class without all the bells and whistels from the previous one:

```
    class tempTest : NSObject {

    var progressView: SwiftProgressView?
    var overlayView: UIView?

    func go(parentView:UIView) {

        if let ov = createOverlay(parentView.frame) {

            if let pv = createProgressView() {

                ov.addSubview(pv)

                parentView.addSubview(ov)

            } else {
                println("Unable to create OverlayView.")
            }

        } else {
            println("Unable to create OverlayView.")
        }


    }

    func createOverlay(frame:CGRect) -> UIView? {
        // Initializing Overlay view
        overlayView = UIView(frame: frame)

        overlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0.3)

        // Adding tap gesture
        let tapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("overlayTapped:"))

        tapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        overlayView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGest)

        // Return the created overlay
        return overlayView
    }

    func createProgressView() -> SwiftProgressView? {

        // Create progressView
        progressView = SwiftProgressView()

        // Configure Options
        progressView?.setIndicatorOfType(SwiftProgressIndicatorType.activityIndicator)
        progressView?.setTitleText("Test")
        progressView?.setDetailText("This is a Test")

        // Return progressView
        return progressView
    }

    func overlayTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        if var pv = progressView {
            pv.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        if var ov = overlayView {
            ov.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // This generates the same error
        // progressView!.removeFromSuperview();
        // overlayView!.removeFromSuperview();

    }

}
```

The app crashes while executing this statement:

```
  pv.removeFromSuperview()
```

If I commentout this code:

```
if var pv = progressView {
    pv.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Then the app does not crash instead it removes the overlay like it should But when I try to display the overlay for a second time it crashes on this statement:

```
  overlayView = UIView(frame: frame)
```

in createOverlay: method

Comment: I am not sure why that works at all - surely you need 'if let xy = AIView {' as ActivityIndicatorView is your type not object?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... it was a typo.

Comment: Hi, I ran your code (replaced SwiftProgressView with a plain UIView) and it ran without any trouble. If you could upload your test project I'd be happily to look further.

Comment: @Ron.Kliffer can you share your xCode version... if the code worked for you then I might be facing a bug... my xCode Version is 6.3.1 (6D1002) ... i think its the latest release idk

Comment: @UmerHassam I'm using the latest Xcode as well

Answer (score 4):

`ActivityIndicatorView` is the type, not the object itself.

You should either do this:

```
if let xy = AIView {
        xy.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

or this:

```
AIView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Also note that a leading capital indicates a type, so this should be `aiView` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad... I typed the code instead of copy and pasting... i've double checked and edited my question... any idea what the issue might be here??

Comment: Plus Thanks for suggesting I should use aiView instead of AIView. i'm sure that will help make my code more readable.

Comment: @RobNapier 'AIView?.removeFromSuperview()' would itself be optional, did you mean to suggest 'AIView!.removeFromSuperview()' ?

Comment: Ron is right. He means ? there. ?. means "call method if this has a value."